# Start CKAN 2.9.X with Gunicorn?

Tags: flask, gunicorn, ckan

Is there a way to start CKAN 2.9 with gunicorn?

I can see from the documentation that gunicorn is mentioned:

> Install Supervisor (a Process Control System) used to control
> starting, stopping the uwsgi or gunicorn servers:

But not much information is in there.

Since 2.9 is flask I was looking at how to serve a flask application with Gunicorn an I came across this post: [How To Serve Flask Applications with Gunicorn and Nginx on Ubuntu 18.04](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-flask-applications-with-gunicorn-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-18-04) and I tried by using this code (wsgi.py):

```
import os
from ckan.config.middleware import make_app
from ckan.cli import CKANConfigLoader
from logging.config import fileConfig as loggingFileConfig

app = None

if __name__ == "__main__":
    config_filepath = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)), 'ckan.ini')
    abspath = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
    loggingFileConfig(config_filepath)
    config = CKANConfigLoader(config_filepath).get_config()
    app = make_app(config)
```

Then running:

```
gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:5000 wsgi:app
```

But I get:

```
[2022-06-22 20:09:34 +0000] [365] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.1.0
[2022-06-22 20:09:34 +0000] [365] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:5000 (365)
[2022-06-22 20:09:34 +0000] [365] [INFO] Using worker: sync
[2022-06-22 20:09:34 +0000] [367] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 367
Failed to find application object: 'app'
[2022-06-22 20:09:35 +0000] [367] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 367)
[2022-06-22 20:09:35 +0000] [365] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
[2022-06-22 20:09:35 +0000] [365] [INFO] Reason: App failed to load.
```

Any idea is appreciated

Comment: Can you try with this file https://github.com/ckan/ckan/blob/dev-v2.9/wsgi.py?

Comment: Yep. And then I use "gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:5000 wsgi:application"  . Many thanks. It works great!